# How to properly script a truncate / insert stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that will truncate a table and load new records using an INSERT statement.  When I run the procedure I see that it executed correctly.  However, when I run a SELECT statement after the procedure ran, I notice that the table is unchanged by the stored procedure.  Do I need to script the procedure differently?

I've reviewed other pages on similar stored procedure topics and scripted my procedure according to others' instructions.  My procedure will run but appears to not do anything.

Here is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test  AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table [Schema].[My table name]'
insert into [Schema].[My table name] (FIELD_ONE, FIELD_TWO) SELECT FIELD_ONE, FIELD_TWO 
FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
WHERE [MY CRITERIA]
END
```

I'm getting a message of "ORA-24344: success with compilation error" for the "Connection" category and "Executed Successfully" for the Statement.  However, I don't see any change to [Schema].[My Table name]

Comment: Resolve the compilation errors.  If it has compilation errors, the procedure cannot be executed.  You should get an error when you try to execute it.  I don't use Toad so don't have advice on that part.  The obvious error in the code you've posted is that you need a semicolon at the end of each statement.

Comment: FYI, both your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and your `INSERT` statements are missing semicolons at the end which would generate syntax errors.  If you are using square brackets around the schema and table names like you would potentially do in SQL Server, that would also be an error.